# why isn't the body wrapping around a div with image background if the content of div is overflowing?

Tags: html, css, frontend

Basically my Html and css is like this:

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    font-size: 20px;
}

html {
    
    height: 100%;
     background: #333; 
    border: 10px solid green;
}

body {
    background:steelblue;
    color: black;
    min-height: 100%;
    border: 10px solid red;
    
    
}


.div1{
    background-image: url("a.jpg");
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    width: 100%;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ab.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="div1">
        <h1>Ankit</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ullam porro vero consequatur laborum a repudiandae rerum
            Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni recusandae quia enim. Minus pariatur, magni,
            officiis autem fuga illo blanditiis adipisci odio, et explicabo eveniet aliquam nesciunt minima debitis dolorum
            laboriosam laborum praesentium assumenda dicta nemo tempora? Temporibus dolore labore quia eaque inventore, earum
            voluptate. Commodi aut voluptas perferendis fugiat placeat rem, alias iusto natus nam, exercitationem porro a
            reprehenderit ab officiis asperiores facilis eveniet inventore, sit perspiciatis blanditiis! Pariatur reiciendis
            magnam modi maiores voluptatem omnis quia! Quisquam sed autem illum natus sapiente quos quidem, rerum numquam
            sit necessitatibus nostrum atque officia sunt animi. Temporibus iure, laudantium dolor explicabo illo, dignissimos
            placeat tenetur nesciunt ipsam libero, aperiam corrupti doloribus officia. Ipsam odio, sapiente nisi ducimus
            voluptatum ex blanditiis corrupti, dolores ratione, quasi neque suscipit vel aperiam fugit magnam. Magni perspiciatis
            rem praesentium adipisci dolorum reprehenderit, corporis sapiente nulla. Delectus accusantium velit ut aspernatur
            nisi impedit iure corporis repellendus tempora a? Nobis, quam sapiente est pariatur, ipsa voluptatum expedita
            rem eaque accusantium tenetur iste voluptatibus dicta beatae sed illo explicabo excepturi cumque eius delectus
            consequatur non praesentium dolores corporis? Impedit deleniti alias explicabo consequuntur dolor quisquam debitis
            facilis cumque natus soluta omnis quod nobis, placeat repellat cupiditate! Vero adipisci nostrum recusandae quo
            dolorem odit expedita, repudiandae, placeat temporibus quod autem excepturi distinctio perspiciatis, illo eius
            magni beatae. Natus fugit esse sunt id cumque blanditiis numquam aperiam. Quidem voluptates neque blanditiis
            sequi quaerat est sint hic sunt, impedit nesciunt consequatur id ipsam nemo in eveniet? Iure voluptatem, inventore
            dolores, nam asperiores possimus commodi quos laborum quidem quasi, sunt libero exercitationem. Iste, enim distinctio!
            Voluptas dicta blanditiis ad ipsa voluptates laudantium, inventore qui, est accusamus impedit officia fuga rerum.
            Repellat eaque aliquid ipsam impedit deleniti atque, consequuntur dicta molestiae. Deleniti corrupti ipsum sapiente,
            sunt at perferendis suscipit tempore a amet officia aut ea pariatur dolores non? Cupiditate repellendus corporis
            sit ex optio soluta quas ea cumque ab delectus quae ipsum at, quisquam numquam, nobis sapiente temporibus cum
            exercitationem placeat laudantium eveniet enim architecto. Ipsum error quisquam dignissimos voluptatem fugiat
            ipsa cupiditate exercitationem consequatur distinctio? Obcaecati sint atque facere veniam iusto repellendus natus
            nobis, commodi cumque ducimus est voluptate, laudantium, perferendis repudiandae voluptates reiciendis. Nisi
            dolorem saepe eaque amet vel ex pariatur ab non autem ut nihil ipsam enim hic reprehenderit voluptatum quae tenetur,
            deleniti alias qui nostrum? Praesentium error hic repellendus officia, distinctio eveniet eos quibusdam in obcaecati
            eius asperiores consectetur quasi, libero, eaque voluptatibus dolor incidunt. Nemo magnam eveniet sit animi fugit
            quas temporibus beatae veniam, aliquam sed voluptas placeat hic qui fugiat illo, omnis totam? Iure voluptatum
            ut, quaerat, nihil inventore doloribus laboriosam expedita, mollitia dolor sequi veniam recusandae aperiam nobis
            illum! A quae ut eos itaque quibusdam magni, non nulla odit voluptatibus dolores exercitationem quidem! Velit
            quis sed autem dolorum sunt itaque, veniam obcaecati quasi architecto culpa? Id ducimus rem iusto optio. Modi
            dolores ad cumque exercitationem, sapiente asperiores in accusantium maxime dicta, earum iste nam consequatur
            excepturi dolorum neque hic necessitatibus, deleniti dolor. Magni dicta excepturi porro repellendus iure blanditiis,
            deserunt voluptas necessitatibus provident debitis doloribus nulla, quo vitae vel, minus dolorum repellat harum
            dolorem deleniti explicabo libero. Ea, atque molestias autem quibusdam placeat fugiat temporibus minima neque.
            Nostrum dolore laudantium eaque! Eligendi rerum ut, at laudantium nesciunt debitis in! Adipisci dicta veniam
            alias error vitae exercitationem quibusdam sequi rem nihil quisquam explicabo qui cum saepe voluptate pariatur,
            quos tium dolore, et tempora sequi atque doloremque eius adipisci
            qui nisi iure facilis voluptatibus accusamus asperiores aspernatur? Molestiae laudantium tenetur laboriosam perspiciatis
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis debitis expedita quam tempora cumque voluptas
            explicabo assumenda ipsa deserunt ut exercitationem ratione cum porro quidem deleniti accusamus in rem, quos
            incidunt temporibus, sed animi rerum atque distinctio! Sed, ullam possimus. Iste magni, sit error perspiciatis
            quidem omnis eveniet doloremque, laboriosam ducimus sequi voluptates labore aliquid harum reprehenderit alias
            itaque cupiditate dolor dolorum quibusdam tenetur molestiae quos id nisi. Ut perspiciatis explicabo obcaecati
            ducimus cupiditate. Iure ad praesentium nesciunt culpa dicta quaerat aspernatur in! Ipsum aspernatur cum sequi
            ab blanditiis doloremque consequatur quod quis eum deleniti voluptatem voluptates amet, error, itaque dolore
            numquam repellat laboriosam hic ex quibusdam totam, vitae maiores! Accusamus sunt, tempora recusandae eaque similique
            nihil consequatur quasi incidunt quo iusto! Voluptatibus, praesentium. Et obcaecati, quod excepturi quae nam
            recusandae magnam! Ipsa accusamus molestiae quasi! Assumenda perspiciatis quod et fuga nihil sed, ipsa deleniti
            tenetur magni iusto! Cum quod repudiandae nemo excepturi earum deleniti delectus iure exercitationem eaque voluptatum
            vitae vetio blanditiis incidunt, aliquid consectetur dicta necessitatibus id! Natus,
            laudantium? Dolor aliquid exercitationem sapiente inventore non ipsam et, nisi nulla molestias optio blanditiis
            consectetur fugit. Beatae molestias iste necessitatibus mollitia quidem corporis tempore? Soluta vitae qui ullam
            culpa in deserunt exercitationem ipsa illum eius, rem omnis ipsum numquam vel temporibus atque dolor cum, velit
            nulla officia perferendis alias optio? Excepturi earum, reiciendis modi velit deleniti placeat sint, aspernatur
            ducimus corporis magnam amet quibusdam, eveniet ea voluptatum laboriosam dignissimos repellat voluptatem ullam
            fugiat ipsum. Consequuntur, blanditiis! Facere placeat earum nostrum iste neque iure. Laborum architecto tempora
            assumenda corporis ut, doloribus, commodi voluptates soluta cumque officia itaque asperiores fugit, harum numquam
            animi eveniet culpa explicabo adipisci debitis nihil suscipit. Illum, debitis totam. Recusandae iusto nam dignissimos
            vitae nisi fuga laboriosam nobis ipsa doloremque natus iure possimus, culpa quia cupiditate laudantium eius tenetur.
            Incidunt suscipit, sit asperiores voluptates facilis illum, veritatis autem vero beatae laborum, alias tenetur.
            Illo possimus pariatur molestias quia optio quis reprehenderit architecto exercitationem distinctio veritatis
            esse, enim culpa, laborum ducimus blanditiis! Aliquam deserunt eligendi ipsa dolorum facere officiis quasi perferendis
            amet doloremque nisi nobis reprehenderit, dolorem aperiam, harum aliquid. Unde aliquam, possimus sit et adipisci,
            aperiam debitis sed asperiores porro facilis veniam dicta? Fugit voluptates repellendus ex alias, architecto
            eos. Molestiae eveniet sunt culpa ex exercitationem eligendi deleniti dignissimos quia, aliquid eum nostrum amet
            expedita aperiam qui dolorem rem doloribus, esse sit? Officia, labore. Assumenda ipsa rem possimus? Vel nostrum
            dignissimos beatae accusantium laborum, unde omnis rem deleniti quidem possimus. Saepe a assumenda iure aliquid
            deleniti omnis odio, quas esse deserunt officia consectetur sequi dolorum, ut magni! Doloribus eaque commodi
            perferendis minus et rerum? Numquam necessitatibus dolore iste possimus cupiditate velit, corrupti at eum, ducimus
            laboriosam provident assumenda voluptatum inventore? Facilis ipsam nihil consequuntur assumenda officia cum nobis
            inventore? Et voluptates dolor nisi deleniti suscipit praesentium. Illum voluptatem perspiciatis placeat aperiam
            fuga laborum corrupti, ipsa aut, perferendis labore ea rem atque recusandae tenetur quaerat dicta quasi totam
            officiis nisi ipsum accusantium corporis. Rem voluptatum neque atque, distinctio est placeat iure quae sed accusantium
            modi quia iste aperiam. Quisquam voluptates magnam, odio eius nisi doloremque error officia asperiores ipsam
            laudantium voluptatibus, culpa voluptate quae esse excepturi nemo adipisci sapiente, ullam aspernatur. Eos, dolores
            dolorum. Voluptates eaque obcaecati, corporis officia omnis aliquam, itaque illum laborum assumenda iusto sapiente
            veritatis praesentium autem adipisci quibusdam? Alias voluptatibus officia ullam voluptatem consequatur accusamus
            ut similique laboriosam ratione, accusantium vitae eaque ab? Sequi excepturi modi repellendus voluptatum error
            consequuntur ex quam, ipsa in hic similique placeat explicabo nisi dicta esse quod molestias maxime magnam! Eos
            ipsum error debitis odio animi, excepturi voluptas tempora ratione hic nihil. Officia aperiam, ipsum voluptatem,
            quibusdam illum officiis odio nam recusandae illo reprehenderit itaque maiores similique ex libero veniam praesentium
            quasi. Quaerat impedit in enim et quisquam at voluptas magni vitae quasi nemo non temporibus saepe facilis accusamus,
            ullam aliquam quibusdam, adipisci ipsum. Quam, adipisci obcaecati repellendus neque sint aliquam in iure, magnam
            aperiam itaque perferendis suscipit vel alias enim dolore. Dolorum ipsa officiis voluptatibus repellat, qui dolore
            incidunt eligendi, dicta natus dignissimos perspiciatis deleniti aspernatur voluptate quos eos! Vitae at placeat
            iste a deserunt quisquam dolorum! Tempora, exercitationem, laborum reprehenderit, odit minima veniam suscipit
            voluptas rem nobis saepe ipsa modi alias hic provident animi atque ab ratione odio a porro eaque distinctio cum
            omnis? Nihil odio distinctio animi minus ducimus necessitatibus tenetur accusantium dolor eaque! Est repellendus,
            laboriosam nostrum ducimus ipsam minima delectus voluptatibus aliquam temporibus nisi qui? Porro eius vero labore
            pariatur molestiae fugit fugiat aliquam nulla soluta illum quod hic beatae laudantium, asperiores laborum repellendus
            quaerat suscipit ipsam nemo perferendis praesentium debitis eligendi consequuntur atque. Reprehenderit laudantium
            quod veniam praesentium rem? Maxime sapiente consequatur alias ducimus nam quis dignissimos, accusantium commodi!</p>
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

`What I want to ask is

1-  Why isn't the body wrapping around the content as the min-height is set to 100% and this works if the content is directly inside the body or if there is no image background with limited height(100vh),an explanation will help a lot(By wrapping i mean that the borders of the body are same as the height of image background and the body  is not adjusting itself according to the overflowing content)?

2- As the body and html are only upto the size of the first page or viewport (as the both borders are ending midway) why the html background color is still applicable over the rest of the content?

3-and if you comment out the background of the html then the background of body will apply to the overflowing content

Thank you for your patience

Answer (score 0):

That's three questions; you should really make it three separate posts next time. But OK.

1. The div has a height of 100vh, so the body doesn't grow larger than that; why should it?
2. The html has a grey background; when you scroll, you scroll the body, not the html. So what you see below the bottom border of the body is the (static) background of the html.
3. For some properties, if the html doesn't have them specified, it takes them from the body. So the html gets the body background in this case. Same for margins.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. If possible can you elaborate the 2nd point a little. What i wanted to ask is if i am  setting the borders of the html and the the background is applied to the whole webpage then why the borders are ending with the image.

Answer (score 0):

The html and body are wrapping around the div, which has a set height, and not the content. Setting the div to min-height and the html to min-height made it wrap around the content.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    font-size: 20px;
}

html {
    
    min-height: 100%;
     background: #333; 
    border: 10px solid green;
}

body {
    background:steelblue;
    color: black;
    min-height: 100%;
    border: 10px solid red;
    
    
}


.div1{
    background-image: url("a.jpg");
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    width: 100%;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ab.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="div1">
        <h1>Ankit</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ullam porro vero consequatur laborum a repudiandae rerum
            Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni recusandae quia enim. Minus pariatur, magni,
            officiis autem fuga illo blanditiis adipisci odio, et explicabo eveniet aliquam nesciunt minima debitis dolorum
            laboriosam laborum praesentium assumenda dicta nemo tempora? Temporibus dolore labore quia eaque inventore, earum
            voluptate. Commodi aut voluptas perferendis fugiat placeat rem, alias iusto natus nam, exercitationem porro a
            reprehenderit ab officiis asperiores facilis eveniet inventore, sit perspiciatis blanditiis! Pariatur reiciendis
            magnam modi maiores voluptatem omnis quia! Quisquam sed autem illum natus sapiente quos quidem, rerum numquam
            sit necessitatibus nostrum atque officia sunt animi. Temporibus iure, laudantium dolor explicabo illo, dignissimos
            placeat tenetur nesciunt ipsam libero, aperiam corrupti doloribus officia. Ipsam odio, sapiente nisi ducimus
            voluptatum ex blanditiis corrupti, dolores ratione, quasi neque suscipit vel aperiam fugit magnam. Magni perspiciatis
            rem praesentium adipisci dolorum reprehenderit, corporis sapiente nulla. Delectus accusantium velit ut aspernatur
            nisi impedit iure corporis repellendus tempora a? Nobis, quam sapiente est pariatur, ipsa voluptatum expedita
            rem eaque accusantium tenetur iste voluptatibus dicta beatae sed illo explicabo excepturi cumque eius delectus
            consequatur non praesentium dolores corporis? Impedit deleniti alias explicabo consequuntur dolor quisquam debitis
            facilis cumque natus soluta omnis quod nobis, placeat repellat cupiditate! Vero adipisci nostrum recusandae quo
            dolorem odit expedita, repudiandae, placeat temporibus quod autem excepturi distinctio perspiciatis, illo eius
            magni beatae. Natus fugit esse sunt id cumque blanditiis numquam aperiam. Quidem voluptates neque blanditiis
            sequi quaerat est sint hic sunt, impedit nesciunt consequatur id ipsam nemo in eveniet? Iure voluptatem, inventore
            dolores, nam asperiores possimus commodi quos laborum quidem quasi, sunt libero exercitationem. Iste, enim distinctio!
            Voluptas dicta blanditiis ad ipsa voluptates laudantium, inventore qui, est accusamus impedit officia fuga rerum.
            Repellat eaque aliquid ipsam impedit deleniti atque, consequuntur dicta molestiae. Deleniti corrupti ipsum sapiente,
            sunt at perferendis suscipit tempore a amet officia aut ea pariatur dolores non? Cupiditate repellendus corporis
            sit ex optio soluta quas ea cumque ab delectus quae ipsum at, quisquam numquam, nobis sapiente temporibus cum
            exercitationem placeat laudantium eveniet enim architecto. Ipsum error quisquam dignissimos voluptatem fugiat
            ipsa cupiditate exercitationem consequatur distinctio? Obcaecati sint atque facere veniam iusto repellendus natus
            nobis, commodi cumque ducimus est voluptate, laudantium, perferendis repudiandae voluptates reiciendis. Nisi
            dolorem saepe eaque amet vel ex pariatur ab non autem ut nihil ipsam enim hic reprehenderit voluptatum quae tenetur,
            deleniti alias qui nostrum? Praesentium error hic repellendus officia, distinctio eveniet eos quibusdam in obcaecati
            eius asperiores consectetur quasi, libero, eaque voluptatibus dolor incidunt. Nemo magnam eveniet sit animi fugit
            quas temporibus beatae veniam, aliquam sed voluptas placeat hic qui fugiat illo, omnis totam? Iure voluptatum
            ut, quaerat, nihil inventore doloribus laboriosam expedita, mollitia dolor sequi veniam recusandae aperiam nobis
            illum! A quae ut eos itaque quibusdam magni, non nulla odit voluptatibus dolores exercitationem quidem! Velit
            quis sed autem dolorum sunt itaque, veniam obcaecati quasi architecto culpa? Id ducimus rem iusto optio. Modi
            dolores ad cumque exercitationem, sapiente asperiores in accusantium maxime dicta, earum iste nam consequatur
            excepturi dolorum neque hic necessitatibus, deleniti dolor. Magni dicta excepturi porro repellendus iure blanditiis,
            deserunt voluptas necessitatibus provident debitis doloribus nulla, quo vitae vel, minus dolorum repellat harum
            dolorem deleniti explicabo libero. Ea, atque molestias autem quibusdam placeat fugiat temporibus minima neque.
            Nostrum dolore laudantium eaque! Eligendi rerum ut, at laudantium nesciunt debitis in! Adipisci dicta veniam
            alias error vitae exercitationem quibusdam sequi rem nihil quisquam explicabo qui cum saepe voluptate pariatur,
            quos tium dolore, et tempora sequi atque doloremque eius adipisci
            qui nisi iure facilis voluptatibus accusamus asperiores aspernatur? Molestiae laudantium tenetur laboriosam perspiciatis
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis debitis expedita quam tempora cumque voluptas
            explicabo assumenda ipsa deserunt ut exercitationem ratione cum porro quidem deleniti accusamus in rem, quos
            incidunt temporibus, sed animi rerum atque distinctio! Sed, ullam possimus. Iste magni, sit error perspiciatis
            quidem omnis eveniet doloremque, laboriosam ducimus sequi voluptates labore aliquid harum reprehenderit alias
            itaque cupiditate dolor dolorum quibusdam tenetur molestiae quos id nisi. Ut perspiciatis explicabo obcaecati
            ducimus cupiditate. Iure ad praesentium nesciunt culpa dicta quaerat aspernatur in! Ipsum aspernatur cum sequi
            ab blanditiis doloremque consequatur quod quis eum deleniti voluptatem voluptates amet, error, itaque dolore
            numquam repellat laboriosam hic ex quibusdam totam, vitae maiores! Accusamus sunt, tempora recusandae eaque similique
            nihil consequatur quasi incidunt quo iusto! Voluptatibus, praesentium. Et obcaecati, quod excepturi quae nam
            recusandae magnam! Ipsa accusamus molestiae quasi! Assumenda perspiciatis quod et fuga nihil sed, ipsa deleniti
            tenetur magni iusto! Cum quod repudiandae nemo excepturi earum deleniti delectus iure exercitationem eaque voluptatum
            vitae vetio blanditiis incidunt, aliquid consectetur dicta necessitatibus id! Natus,
            laudantium? Dolor aliquid exercitationem sapiente inventore non ipsam et, nisi nulla molestias optio blanditiis
            consectetur fugit. Beatae molestias iste necessitatibus mollitia quidem corporis tempore? Soluta vitae qui ullam
            culpa in deserunt exercitationem ipsa illum eius, rem omnis ipsum numquam vel temporibus atque dolor cum, velit
            nulla officia perferendis alias optio? Excepturi earum, reiciendis modi velit deleniti placeat sint, aspernatur
            ducimus corporis magnam amet quibusdam, eveniet ea voluptatum laboriosam dignissimos repellat voluptatem ullam
            fugiat ipsum. Consequuntur, blanditiis! Facere placeat earum nostrum iste neque iure. Laborum architecto tempora
            assumenda corporis ut, doloribus, commodi voluptates soluta cumque officia itaque asperiores fugit, harum numquam
            animi eveniet culpa explicabo adipisci debitis nihil suscipit. Illum, debitis totam. Recusandae iusto nam dignissimos
            vitae nisi fuga laboriosam nobis ipsa doloremque natus iure possimus, culpa quia cupiditate laudantium eius tenetur.
            Incidunt suscipit, sit asperiores voluptates facilis illum, veritatis autem vero beatae laborum, alias tenetur.
            Illo possimus pariatur molestias quia optio quis reprehenderit architecto exercitationem distinctio veritatis
            esse, enim culpa, laborum ducimus blanditiis! Aliquam deserunt eligendi ipsa dolorum facere officiis quasi perferendis
            amet doloremque nisi nobis reprehenderit, dolorem aperiam, harum aliquid. Unde aliquam, possimus sit et adipisci,
            aperiam debitis sed asperiores porro facilis veniam dicta? Fugit voluptates repellendus ex alias, architecto
            eos. Molestiae eveniet sunt culpa ex exercitationem eligendi deleniti dignissimos quia, aliquid eum nostrum amet
            expedita aperiam qui dolorem rem doloribus, esse sit? Officia, labore. Assumenda ipsa rem possimus? Vel nostrum
            dignissimos beatae accusantium laborum, unde omnis rem deleniti quidem possimus. Saepe a assumenda iure aliquid
            deleniti omnis odio, quas esse deserunt officia consectetur sequi dolorum, ut magni! Doloribus eaque commodi
            perferendis minus et rerum? Numquam necessitatibus dolore iste possimus cupiditate velit, corrupti at eum, ducimus
            laboriosam provident assumenda voluptatum inventore? Facilis ipsam nihil consequuntur assumenda officia cum nobis
            inventore? Et voluptates dolor nisi deleniti suscipit praesentium. Illum voluptatem perspiciatis placeat aperiam
            fuga laborum corrupti, ipsa aut, perferendis labore ea rem atque recusandae tenetur quaerat dicta quasi totam
            officiis nisi ipsum accusantium corporis. Rem voluptatum neque atque, distinctio est placeat iure quae sed accusantium
            modi quia iste aperiam. Quisquam voluptates magnam, odio eius nisi doloremque error officia asperiores ipsam
            laudantium voluptatibus, culpa voluptate quae esse excepturi nemo adipisci sapiente, ullam aspernatur. Eos, dolores
            dolorum. Voluptates eaque obcaecati, corporis officia omnis aliquam, itaque illum laborum assumenda iusto sapiente
            veritatis praesentium autem adipisci quibusdam? Alias voluptatibus officia ullam voluptatem consequatur accusamus
            ut similique laboriosam ratione, accusantium vitae eaque ab? Sequi excepturi modi repellendus voluptatum error
            consequuntur ex quam, ipsa in hic similique placeat explicabo nisi dicta esse quod molestias maxime magnam! Eos
            ipsum error debitis odio animi, excepturi voluptas tempora ratione hic nihil. Officia aperiam, ipsum voluptatem,
            quibusdam illum officiis odio nam recusandae illo reprehenderit itaque maiores similique ex libero veniam praesentium
            quasi. Quaerat impedit in enim et quisquam at voluptas magni vitae quasi nemo non temporibus saepe facilis accusamus,
            ullam aliquam quibusdam, adipisci ipsum. Quam, adipisci obcaecati repellendus neque sint aliquam in iure, magnam
            aperiam itaque perferendis suscipit vel alias enim dolore. Dolorum ipsa officiis voluptatibus repellat, qui dolore
            incidunt eligendi, dicta natus dignissimos perspiciatis deleniti aspernatur voluptate quos eos! Vitae at placeat
            iste a deserunt quisquam dolorum! Tempora, exercitationem, laborum reprehenderit, odit minima veniam suscipit
            voluptas rem nobis saepe ipsa modi alias hic provident animi atque ab ratione odio a porro eaque distinctio cum
            omnis? Nihil odio distinctio animi minus ducimus necessitatibus tenetur accusantium dolor eaque! Est repellendus,
            laboriosam nostrum ducimus ipsam minima delectus voluptatibus aliquam temporibus nisi qui? Porro eius vero labore
            pariatur molestiae fugit fugiat aliquam nulla soluta illum quod hic beatae laudantium, asperiores laborum repellendus
            quaerat suscipit ipsam nemo perferendis praesentium debitis eligendi consequuntur atque. Reprehenderit laudantium
            quod veniam praesentium rem? Maxime sapiente consequatur alias ducimus nam quis dignissimos, accusantium commodi!</p>
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Actually i already knew that what i wanted to ask is whether the overflowing content will go just outside the div  or outside the body too(which is happening in this case ) if the body is at adjustable height(min-height)

Comment: @AnkitBrahmbhatt If the content is wrapped in a div, the body will go around the div, not the content. Therefore the overflowing content will go out of the body, even if the body has adjustable height

Comment: Ohh I get it now. Thank you for that